# Numbered list with text ellipse hides the order numbers also

Tags: html, css

I am working on a ol list with text ellipse but when i add `overflow: hidden ;` property it also hides the numeric order.

How can i use `text ellipse` and also keep numbers visible

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zjKwwM)

```css
.wrapper{width:300px; background-color:#ccc; padding:10px;}
.tab-ol li { 
list-style-position:inside;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: visible;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  
}
.ol-2 li{
  list-style-position:inside;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden ;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;  
}
ol {
 counter-reset:li; /* Initiate a counter */
 margin-left:0; /* Remove the default left margin */
 padding-left:0; /* Remove the default left padding */
}
ol > li {
 position:relative; /* Create a positioning context */
 margin:0 0 6px 2em; /* Give each list item a left margin to make room for the numbers */
 padding:4px 8px; /* Add some spacing around the content */
 list-style:none; /* Disable the normal item numbering */
 border-top:0px solid #666;
 background:#f6f6f6;
}
ol > li:before {
 content:counter(li); /* Use the counter as content */
 counter-increment:li; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
 /* Position and style the number */
 position:absolute;
 top:-2px;
 left:-2em;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 width:2em;
 /* Some space between the number and the content in browsers that support
    generated content but not positioning it (Camino 2 is one example) */
 margin-right:8px;
 padding:4px;
 border-top:0px solid #666;
 color:#fff;
 background:#666;
 font-weight:bold;
 /* font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif; */
 text-align:center;
}
li ol,
li ul {margin-top:6px;}
ol ol li:last-child {margin-bottom:0;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<ol class="tab-ol">
<li>This is article number one for this month</li>
<li>This is article number one for this month</li> 
<li>This is article number one for this month</li>
<li>This is article number one for this month</li>
</ol> 
</div>
<p>ANOTHER LIST WITH HIDDEN NUMBER</p>
<div class="wrapper">
<ol class="tab-ol ol-2">
<li>This is article number one for this month</li>
<li>This is article number one for this month</li> 
<li>This is article number one for this month</li>
<li>This is article number one for this month</li>
</ol> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace margin with padding and make the number inside li:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.tab-ol li {
  list-style-position: inside;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: li;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ol>li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 0 6px 0;/*remove the margin here*/
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 2.1em;/* Add the padding here*/
  list-style: none;
  border-top: 0px solid #666;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}

ol>li:before {
  content: counter(li);
  counter-increment: li;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;/*adjust the new position*/
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 2em;
  padding: 4px;
  border-top: 0px solid #666;
  color: #fff;
  background: #666;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

li ol,
li ul {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

ol ol li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ol class="tab-ol">
    <li>This is article number one for this month</li>
    <li>This is article number one for this month</li>
    <li>This is article number one for this month</li>
    <li>This is article number one for this month</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to add `margin-right:10px;` to add some space to following class `ol > li:before{}` but is not working

Comment: @Learning it won't because it has absolute position so the margin won't affect the text .. instead consider making the padding of the text bigger

Comment: Only that works i tried that i have to change all the padding, any ways thanks  as it server my purpose...

Comment: @Learning you ma also remove the position absolute and then you can adjust with margin and get rid of padding

Comment: I had changed position to relative and made change to padding, it is fine but not as good as it look with absolute position. i think i need to get the right combination